# Again about combobox and autocomplete on c#

Tags: c#

Please, help me to make method, when user type some words in ComboBox, works DropDownList and offer list with all matches, not just the first letters (standard method autocomplete)

I tried to write it myself, but the behavior of the control does not work so well as when using AutoCompleteMode

I can not do it 2 months, find this in all web page, looking codeproject, and it seems a long time, I found this site a method that use autocomplete, but before change API.

Sorry for my language (i was helped by google translate)

P.S.
I'm use WinForms

Comment: You said you tried to write it yourself, paste the code you wrote in order for others to help you correct it.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this ...

Call the function AutoComplete from within the ComboBox's KeyPress event handler.

```
 AutoComplete(ComboBox cb, System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs e, bool blnLimitToList)

 // AutoComplete
public void AutoComplete(ComboBox cb, System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
      this.AutoComplete(cb, e, false);
}

public void AutoComplete(ComboBox cb,System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs e, bool blnLimitToList)
{
     string strFindStr = "";

     if (e.KeyChar == (char)8) 
     {
         if (cb.SelectionStart <= 1) 
         {
             cb.Text = "";
             return;
         }

        if (cb.SelectionLength == 0)
            strFindStr = cb.Text.Substring(0, cb.Text.Length - 1);
        else 
           strFindStr = cb.Text.Substring(0, cb.SelectionStart - 1);
     }
    else 
    {
         if (cb.SelectionLength == 0)
            strFindStr = cb.Text + e.KeyChar;
         else
             strFindStr = cb.Text.Substring(0, cb.SelectionStart) + e.KeyChar;
     }

   int intIdx = -1;

    // Search the string in the ComboBox list.

     intIdx = cb.FindString(strFindStr);

     if (intIdx != -1)
     {
             cb.SelectedText = "";
             cb.SelectedIndex = intIdx;
             cb.SelectionStart = strFindStr.Length;
             cb.SelectionLength = cb.Text.Length;
             e.Handled = true;
      }
      else
      {
           e.Handled = blnLimitToList;
       }
  }
```

I hope it will helps you....