# AutoComplete comboBox does not suggest when the text copied and pasted into comboBox in c# winform VS2012

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, combobox, autocomplete

I have made a autocomplete comboBox in c# windows form application using Visual Studio 2012. It is working correctly. That means when I type text in that comboBox it suggest me the options. But when I copy and paste something into the comboBox it does not show any suggestions. But I want to show the suggestions when user copy and paste text into the comboBox.
Could you please help me to fix this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try to call your function on 'GetFocu' or 'KeyUp' event or both :-D

Comment: could you please explain a little bit ?

Answer (score 0):

when you have created your comboBox, you can add events.
so, add to your comboBox thes two event like this :

```
<ComboBox OnFocus="YourAutoCompletionFunction" KeyUp="YourAutoCompletionFunction" />
// if your comboBox has others properties, keep them, just add onFocus and KeyUp events
```

if you haven't a autocompletion function, you can found some here : 
[Again about combobox and autocomplete on c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846840/again-about-combobox-and-autocomplete-on-c-sharp)

Comment: what are the parameter values to call AutoComplete(ComboBox cb, System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs e, bool blnLimitToList)

Answer (score 0):

Parameters are automatically written by Visual Studio...
You just need to give a name for the function and add content to the function...